# Handling Third Party Cookies on WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I need a way to accept/handle third party cookies in WKWebViews for iOS 13.5. It seems iOS is blocking my site from fully loading due to third party cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WKWebView does not support third-party cookies. Change your site to work without them.